# Is there a Bukkit plug-in that will prevent Ghasts from spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

We planned to create some big buildings in the Nether but to make it challenging on the earth too, we do enable enemies.

However, we don't want to enable Ghasts as we find them very annoying since they destroy everything.

Is there a Bukkit plug-in that allows me to disable ghasts?

Comment: I think worldguard lets you stop them from blowing up things, but not player damage?

Comment: You could also just build it so that it's spawn-proof. That's part of the challenge of vanilla.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the very simple (yet effective) [WhichMobs](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-whichmobs-v-1-0-choose-which-mobs-spawn-818.13235/) plugin, to explicitly turn off certain mobs from spawning. All it would take is a simple `ghast = false` in the property file for the plugin to turn Ghasts off. You could also use [NoSpawn](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-mech-nospawn-v1-5-3-stop-mobs-from-spawning-1000.13926/) and [MobToggle](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-mech-mobtoggle-v1-0-simple-monster-animal-on-off-1060.30731/), all of which accomplish the same thing.

Also, if you would like to keep Ghasts floating around but at the same time don't want them to destroy your buildings, you could install [StopMob](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-stopmob-1-0-stop-them-mobs-attacking-1060.32212/), which will stop mobs from being aggressive, yet keeps them in the game.

Comment: StopMob is a very good idea!

Answer (score 5):

I have been informed that my answer is outdated.  So I would like to suggest another:

[Crowd Control.](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-crowdcontrol-v0-27-04-the-creature-control-plugin-1000.20556/)

It won't stop ghasts from spawning, but you can make them passive.

If you *really* don't want them, [WorldGuard](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Configuration/Bukkit) appears to let you blacklist certain mobs from spawning.

---

**BEGIN ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

> Yes there is.  It's called [Moblimiter](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/inactive-admn-moblimiter-v1-1-set-creature-limits-and-blacklists-617.10804/).
>
> *Disclaimer:*  I haven't tried it, but the forum thread specifically
>   says "Blacklist specific creatures".

Comment: Approved, this mod works perfectly :) It also allows to set a maximum mobs spawned on the server at a time, in order to limit RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla, you can specify `/gamerule mobGriefing false` so they won't blow things up.

Comment: I suspect the asker wanted Creepers to function normally ("make it challenging on the earth").