# Bukkit plugin to control which mobs spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'd like mobs to spawn on my server: just skeletons and zombies though. I don't want those meddling creepers putting pockmarks in our architecture.

Is there a (current and up-to-date) server-side Bukkit plugin to control which mobs can spawn, and which cannot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: "[Is there a Bukkit plug-in that will prevent Ghasts from spawning?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29318/5029)"?

Comment: I believe the answers to the question I linked should answer your question as well.

Comment: @John The questions *are* duplicates, but it seems WTP actually wanted a plugin that stopped Ghasts from shooting fireballs (making the questions slightly different).

Comment: @KevinY And he wants a plugin to make a few different monsters not spawn.  I don't think that's different enough to warrant splitting the attention (votes, answers, page-views, etc.)

Comment: @John I suppose they are fairly similar questions. I'll delete my answer (since they are very duplicate-*y*) and vote to close.

Comment: Just because the questions are similar doesn't make them duplicates.  In fact, the two things (similar, and duplicate) have completely different meanings. (@john)

Comment: No, my question is not a duplicate, because I am not trying to prevent Ghasts from spawning. Nor does the answer to that question answer this one, since the only mod in that question which is not world-breakingly out of date _doesn't do what I'm asking for._

Comment: There are two criteria I use for duplicate questions: A) Are they asking the same thing? _no, ghasts is only a small subset of this request_ B) Would the answer for the older question be correct for the newer one? _no, because the other answer is useless, and a future technically correct answer would be a mod which blocks exclusively ghasts, and then I will have no answer because you closed the question about controlling other monsters. However, this question's answer would be an adequate response to the Ghasts question, so if anything it should be closed as a duplicate of **this** question_

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Perhaps in future offering a bounty on a question with an outdated answer might be a better way forward?

Comment: Part of my duplicate criteria is that one question is contained entirely within the other.  This may be the better/more general question, but I still say they are dupes.  (@jjnguy)

Comment: [Meta discussion started...](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2990/5029)

Comment: @fredley The question in question is asking about Ghasts. An answer to that question will probably not answer this one because I care about all mobs, not just ghasts. It is pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WorldGuard](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-worldguard-5-3-block-fire-ice-melt-mushrooms-advanced-fast-area-protect-blacklist-1185.790/) ([Download](https://github.com/sk89q/worldguard/downloads)) appears to have the [ability to prevent certain mobs from spawning](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Configuration/Bukkit)
(Control+F ->  "block-creature-spawn").

At the time of this writing, it appears to be up to date.

Comment: Its official bukkit link: [WorldGuard](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-worldguard-5-3-block-fire-ice-melt-mushrooms-advanced-fast-area-protect-blacklist-1185.790/). It's up to date at the time I write this.

Answer (score 1):

[StopMob](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-stopmob-1-26-stop-them-mobs-attacking-permissions-1185.32212/) sounds like what you want. While it won't stop mobs from spawning, it will stop them attacking, i.e. creepers won't be able to explode and damage your buildings.

Keeping them around means you'll still be able to get gunpowder, which is a bonus!

Comment: Fair point. Mobtoggle is still being updated, but doesn't do what you want (blanket agressive/passive mob bans).

Comment: Whilst StopMob is useful in a hackish sort of way, it doesn't solve my issue if I don't want them spawning in the first place.

Comment: Your question seemed to imply it was the creepers' explosions you were worried about, is that not the case?

Comment: Yes. It's also the case I'm asking for spawn control. In my case specifically, PermissionsEx can already give me pacifism (you can revoke a user's permission to be targeted by mobs or specific mobs, if you can believe it), and I have alternative sources of gunpowder available. Having harmless creepers is kinda cool, but not what I'm after in this question.